# Angularjs custom service variable undefined by $http success

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote an angular service that is supposed to load customer details over http and store them for future use (in a singleton pattern).

However, when the http call returns successfuly, the variable into which I want to inject the data is undefined and an error is thrown.

Here's the code:

```
NBApp.service("serverDataService", ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var currentMemberDetails = [];

    this.currentMember = function (){
        if (this.currentMemberDetails.length>0)
            return this.currentMemberDetails[0];
        return null;
    };

    this.getMemberDetails = function (cardId) {
        //TBD - call members details web service
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'resources/customer.json'
        }).then
        (
            function success(response) {
                this.currentMemberDetails.push(response.data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            function failure(response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}]);
```

The `currentMemberDetails` is undefined, as shown by the chrome dev console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.currentMemberDetails.push(response.data);
```

Use

```
currentMemberDetails.push(response.data);
```